# LinkMovementMethod causes editing issue in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to create a general rich text editor in Android using EditText widget (should support text formatting, links and inserting pictures in text).
The problem is that to enable handling the clicks to a hyperlinks, I need to assign LinkMovementMethod to the widget as:

```
textEditor.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Unfortunately, this causes the editor to behave strangely. If I want to edit existing text content and I touch somewhere in the middle of the text, when I start typing, text is actually added at the start of the widget, before the existing text, not at the touch point.
If I do not use LinkMovementMethod, editing works fine, but in this case my links are not clickable anymore.

What can I do here? Does anyone know a good example of modified version of LinkMovementMethod class?
Any tips?

Comment: I have the same issue. When I use LinkMovementMethod I cannot select a text from TextView on long click. No action bar or menu as usually without LinkMovementMethod.

Comment: Hi! Do you solved this problem? I'm interesting in answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try it :-
add this class in your project

```
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.Selection;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod;
import android.text.method.MovementMethod;
import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Nishu on 20-08-2015.
 */
public class MyMovementMethod extends ArrowKeyMovementMethod {

private static MyMovementMethod sInstance;

public static MovementMethod getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new MyMovementMethod ();
    }
    return sInstance;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, Spannable buffer, MotionEvent   event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
            action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
        y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

        x += widget.getScrollX();
        y += widget.getScrollY();

        Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
        int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
        int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

        ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off,  ClickableSpan.class);

        if (link.length != 0) {
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                link[0].onClick(widget);
            }
            else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Selection.setSelection(buffer, buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]),  buffer.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
            }

            return true;
        }
        /*else {
            that's the line we need to remove
            Selection.removeSelection(buffer);
        }*/
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
 }

}
```

now add below line of code with your EditText

```
YourEditText.setMovementMethod(MyMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and remove all type of setMovementMethods from editText

Answer (score 0):

@user5211136 answer solved the problem for me and works very nicely!
Since our app is written in Kotlin, here is the Kotlin version. The lazy initialization approach / singleton approach was removed although. Didn't seem necessary but works too (tested it before I removed it).

```
class MyMovementMethod : ArrowKeyMovementMethod() {

override fun onTouchEvent(
    widget: TextView,
    buffer: Spannable,
    event: MotionEvent
): Boolean {
    val action = event.action
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
        action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
    ) {
        var x = event.x.toInt()
        var y = event.y.toInt()
        x -= widget.totalPaddingLeft
        y -= widget.totalPaddingTop
        x += widget.scrollX
        y += widget.scrollY
        val layout: Layout = widget.layout
        val line: Int = layout.getLineForVertical(y)
        val off: Int = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x.toFloat())
        val link = buffer.getSpans(
            off, off,
            ClickableSpan::class.java
        )
        if (link.isNotEmpty()) {
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                link[0].onClick(widget)
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Selection.setSelection(
                    buffer, buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]), buffer.getSpanEnd(
                        link[0]
                    )
                )
            }
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event)
}}
```

Add the class to your project and call it like this:

```
YourEditText.movementMethod = MyMovementMethod()
```